# Wait free triple buffer primitive

Tags: performance, thread-safety, rust

I'm trying to write a triple buffer that's wait free for a update + render loop after being bitten by lock starvation one too many times (on a different project, using a library).

For reference, a triple buffer is effectively a single producer, single consumer channel, that allows for the producer to update the buffer while the consumer can always get the most recently updated buffer. Since the renderer only needs the most recent state to extrapolate a (soon to be) future state and the simulation could update many times in between, this fits. Since simulation data tends to update EVERYTHING as well as being kind of arbitrary, I wanted the write and read to be entirely unrestricted in what could be done to the buffers. Since I had to deal with starving rendering threads in the last assignment, I decided to make it lock free, then stumbled on what I think is wait free as well (it's effectively a single `fetch_nand` statement).

Here's the code (same as on [GitHub](https://github.com/AlterionX/totality-rs/tree/master/totality-sync)):

```rust
use std::{
    cell::UnsafeCell,
    fmt::Debug,
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicBool, AtomicUsize},
        Arc,
    },
};

use cb::utils::CachePadded;

#[allow(unused_imports)]
use log::{debug, error, info, trace, warn};

pub fn buffer<T: Clone>(src: T) -> (ReadingView<T>, EditingView<T>) {
    TripleBuffer::alloc(src)
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TripleBufferIndices {
    snatched_read: CachePadded<usize>,     // unique
    packed_vals: CachePadded<AtomicUsize>, // shared
    stale: CachePadded<AtomicBool>,        // shared
    edit_rw: CachePadded<(usize, usize)>,  // unique
}
impl TripleBufferIndices {
    #[inline]
    fn pack(v0: usize, v1: usize) -> usize {
        (0b0 << 4) + (v0 << 2) + ((!v1) & 0b11)
    }
    #[inline]
    fn unpack(packed: usize) -> (usize, usize) {
        let should_negate = ((packed >> 4) & 0b1) != 0;
        let most_recent = (if should_negate { !packed } else { packed } >> 2) & 0b11;
        let next_write = !packed & 0b11;
        (most_recent, next_write)
    }
    fn snatch(&mut self) {
        let mask = (0b1 << 4)
            + (0b11 << 2)
            + match *self.snatched_read {
                0 => 0b00,
                1 => 0b01,
                2 => 0b10,
                _ => panic!("We done goofed!"),
            };
        let old_snatched = self.snatched_read;
        if !self.stale.swap(true, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Acquire) {
            *self.snatched_read = Self::unpack(
                self.packed_vals
                    .fetch_nand(mask, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::AcqRel),
            )
            .0;
            trace!(
                "Snatching indices {:?} and returning indices {:?}.",
                old_snatched,
                self.snatched_read
            );
        }
    }
    fn advance(&mut self) {
        let next_write = Self::unpack(self.packed_vals.swap(
            Self::pack(self.edit_rw.1, self.edit_rw.1),
            std::sync::atomic::Ordering::AcqRel,
        ))
        .1;
        self.stale.swap(false, std::sync::atomic::Ordering::Release);
        trace!(
            "Advancing indices from {:?} to {:?}.",
            self.edit_rw.1,
            next_write
        );
        self.edit_rw.0 = self.edit_rw.1;
        self.edit_rw.1 = next_write;
    }
}
impl Default for TripleBufferIndices {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            snatched_read: CachePadded::new(0),
            packed_vals: CachePadded::new(AtomicUsize::new(Self::pack(0, 2))),
            stale: CachePadded::new(AtomicBool::new(true)),
            edit_rw: CachePadded::new((1, 2)),
        }
    }
}

struct TripleBuffer<T: Clone> {
    ii: UnsafeCell<TripleBufferIndices>,
    backing_mem: *const [UnsafeCell<CachePadded<T>>; 3],
    tt: [*mut T; 3],
}
impl<T: Clone> TripleBuffer<T> {
    pub fn alloc(src: T) -> (ReadingView<T>, EditingView<T>) {
        let backing_mem = Box::into_raw(Box::new([
            UnsafeCell::new(CachePadded::new(src.clone())),
            UnsafeCell::new(CachePadded::new(src.clone())),
            UnsafeCell::new(CachePadded::new(src)),
        ]));
        let mut tt: [*mut T; 3] = unsafe { std::mem::uninitialized() };
        unsafe {
            for i in 0..3 {
                tt[i] = &mut **(*backing_mem)[i].get();
            }
        }
        let arc = Arc::new(Self {
            ii: UnsafeCell::new(TripleBufferIndices::default()),
            backing_mem,
            tt,
        });
        (ReadingView(arc.clone()), EditingView(arc))
    }
    fn snatch(&self) {
        let ii = self.ii.get();
        unsafe { (*ii).snatch() };
    }
    fn advance(&self) {
        let ii = self.ii.get();
        unsafe { (*ii).advance() };
    }
    fn rr(&self) -> *const T {
        let ii = self.ii.get();
        self.tt[unsafe { *(*ii).snatched_read }]
    }
    fn er(&self) -> *const T {
        let ii = self.ii.get();
        self.tt[unsafe { (*ii).edit_rw.0 }]
    }
    fn ew(&self) -> *mut T {
        let ii = self.ii.get();
        self.tt[unsafe { (*ii).edit_rw.1 }]
    }
}
impl<T: Clone> Drop for TripleBuffer<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(self.backing_mem as *mut [CachePadded<T>; 3]);
        };
    }
}

pub struct RWPair<R, W> {
    r: R,
    w: W,
}

pub enum Reading<T: Clone> {
    ReadingView(ReadingView<T>),
    Reader(Reader<T>),
}
pub struct ReadingView<T: Clone>(Arc<TripleBuffer<T>>);
impl<T: Clone> ReadingView<T> {
    pub fn read(self) -> Reader<T> {
        Reader::from_view(self)
    }
}
unsafe impl<T: Clone> Send for ReadingView<T> {}
pub struct Reader<T: Clone> {
    origin: ReadingView<T>,
    locker: *const T,
}
impl<T: Clone> Reader<T> {
    pub fn from_view(rv: ReadingView<T>) -> Reader<T> {
        rv.0.snatch();
        Self {
            locker: rv.0.rr(),
            origin: rv,
        }
    }
    pub fn r<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T {
        unsafe { &*self.locker }
    }
    pub fn release(self) -> ReadingView<T> {
        self.origin
    }
}

pub enum Editing<T: Clone> {
    EditingView(EditingView<T>),
    Editor(Editor<T>),
}
pub struct EditingView<T: Clone>(Arc<TripleBuffer<T>>);
impl<T: Clone> EditingView<T> {
    pub fn edit(self) -> Editor<T> {
        Editor::from_view(self)
    }
}
unsafe impl<T: Clone> Send for EditingView<T> {}
pub struct Editor<T: Clone> {
    origin: EditingView<T>,
    rw_lock: RWPair<*const T, *mut T>,
}
impl<T: Clone> Editor<T> {
    fn from_view(ev: EditingView<T>) -> Editor<T> {
        Editor {
            rw_lock: RWPair {
                r: ev.0.er(),
                w: ev.0.ew(),
            },
            origin: ev,
        }
    }
    pub fn r<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T {
        unsafe { &*self.rw_lock.r }
    }
    pub fn w<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a mut T {
        unsafe { &mut *self.rw_lock.w }
    }
    pub fn release(self) -> EditingView<T> {
        self.origin.0.advance();
        self.origin
    }
}
```

And you can run it like this:

```rust
fn sort_of_a_test() {
    let (rv, ev) = tb::buffer([0u8; 1_000]);
    let e_th = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut ev = Some(ev);
        let mut e = None;
        for _ in 0..255 {
            e.replace(ev.take().unwrap().edit());
            // do some editing
            let e_int = e.as_ref().unwrap();
            for (rv, ev) in e_int.r().iter().zip(e_int.w().iter_mut()) {
                *ev = *rv + 1;
            }
            ev.replace(e.take().unwrap().release());
        }
    });
    let r_th = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut rv = Some(rv);
        let mut r = None;
        let mut scratch = 0;
        loop {
            r.replace(rv.take().unwrap().read());
            // do some reading
            for v in r.as_ref().unwrap().r().iter() {
                scratch = *v;
            }
            rv.replace(r.take().unwrap().release());
            if scratch == 255 {
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    e_th.join().expect("Failed to join editing thread.");
    r_th.join().expect("Failed to join reading thread.");
}
```

EDIT: As a side note, I would like to avoid the Option swap there, if possible.

EDIT 2: Forgot to mention, `cb` is the `crossbeam` crate.

Comment: Didn't fully read your code, but I've experimented with multiple triple-buffer designs, and settled on an array of three `UnsafeCell<T>` and a single atomic byte as state (probably simpler than your design). I found a mature crate implementing this scheme at https://github.com/HadrienG2/triple-buffer, and multiple people have independently discovered equivalent formulations: https://github.com/Ralith/oddio/blob/main/src/swap.rs and https://github.com/nyanpasu64/spectro2/blob/master/flip-cell/src/lib.rs.